# How nats.io resolve domains when discovers routes?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, nats.io

If I specify route for nats.io like

`nats-route://ruser:T0pS3cr3t@nats.cluster1:622`

`nats.cluster1` - is domain in aws Route53 managed by aws/ecs/service_discovery. It may have random number of A records.

Will `nats.io` resolve `nats.cluster1` to get a list of A records and wait `TTL` time to resolve again?

or will it resolve using something like `gethostbyname` and use that resolve `ip` forever ?